# Do System Verilog coverpoints and covergroups work for real variable types?

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions, cadence

I'm looking into using coverpoints and covergroups for mixed signal verification in Cadence to verify some constrained random classes I've written.  However, I haven't been able to find online if coverpoints can be used for reals.  In fact, I've found some older articles saying they're not supported.  Can coverpoints be used to verify reals and if so what additional syntax in necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The [SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) section 19.5 says

> A coverage point specifies an integral expression that is to be
> covered.

The *bin* structure of `coverpoint` is defined using equality operations, which real numbers has problems with approximation.